# Improve / simplify / convoluted IIF statement

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, bids

I have a moderately complex report and toward the bottom I have some summary / calculations being done on the above data. One such calculation simply adds various fields across the report. For example: TextBx1 + Txtbx2 + Txtbx3 etc. Now this might be OK if it was one off but I actually want to do an IIF with it and that IIF statement gets quite long and convoluted.
For example:

```
IIF((TextBx1 + Txtbx2 + Txtbx3...) > 0, (TextBx1 + Txtbx2 + Txtbx3...), Format(0, "F0"))
     ------Eval section--------------    -------------True----------     -----False----
```

It would be easier to read AND maintain if I could put this val into a variable as such:

```
IIF(Variables!SumTxt1_10 > 0, Variables!SumTxt1_10, Format(0, "F0"))
```

However when I try to use a variable in such a manner I get Variable values cannot be used in report language expressions.

How can I clean up or improve this IIF?

Comment: Convoluted IIF statements are the SSRS way.  Perhaps you could add a calculated field to your dataset and use that for the logic.  Keep it hidden and only display the result in the target column.

Comment: Well....based upon your comment I tried to think of ways to improve my sql to reduce reporting logic operations and I came up with a way so...why not turn your comment into an answer and I'll mark it correct.